# Storing ArrayList value in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, session-variables

I have a particular problem regarding the **Session["arr3"]** and an ArrayList: "**arr3**".

I have stored certain values in Session["arr3"] , and upon the click event of a button e.g. '**btnSpclins_Click**', I want to assign the Session["arr3"] the following values:- 

**Session["arr3"] = Session["arr3"] + arr3;**

But I am recieving the following compilation error:-
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'System.Collections.ArrayList'


Or I may make it simple as:-
**Session["arr3"] += arr3;**

 This is causing the following compilation error:- 
 
"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'System.Collections.ArrayList'".

**OBJECTIVE**: The objective to do this is to hold the  Session["arr3"]'s values (this is what I am referring to old value of  Session["arr3"] ), and then add the ArrayList arr3's values to the  Session["arr3"], and then these two combined values ( Session["arr3"] + arr3) are then stored in the  Session["arr3"]. Now this will be the new  Session["arr3"]'s value. This value will be saved/inserted in a DB Table.

I want to retain the old value of Session["arr3"], and add the old value with the arr3(ArrayList) value and save in the Session["arr3"]. And this final Session["arr3"] value is inserted in a Database's Table.

Please help me in this aspect at earliest.

Comment: what do you *really* want to achieve? It's unclear to me what *"add the old value with the arr3(ArrayList) value"* should mean

Comment: You need to add the arr3 element to the arraylist stored in the session?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I have revised the question, you may re-read it.

Comment: I think you need to provide further code samples to get any more help with this, probably in a separate question, as part of the original question (how to append to an ArrayList in session) has now been answered.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you have an existing ArrayList in session.  You also have a new ArrayList called arr3 and you want to join them together, storing the result back in the session.

If so, you need to cast your session object back to what it is before appending the new elements:

```
Session["arr3"] = ((ArrayList)Session["arr3"]).AddRange(arr3);
```

This will take the original ArrayList from the session, append the elements in arr3, and put it back in the session.

Comment: This is not the scenario, I have revised the question, please read my question again. Please help me in this aspect at earliest.

Comment: You haven't stated what type Session["arr3"] is - also an `ArrayList`?  Also, why do you need to put them in session before inserting to database?  What have you tried on the database side of things?

Comment: (1)-Session["arr3"] and ArrayList "arr3" both are holding some string values, which will be inserted in the DB Table, at the click event of another Button-click 'btnSpclins_Click'. (2)- I have  few controls which capture data and insert into the DB's Table and hence shown in the GridView, I want to do is that when the user inserts multiple entry, then these all entries must be held in the Session and then all these entries are to be sent in an E-mail Relay to concerned people. Currently the last entry is only sent through E-mail Relay, so I need to cater all entries(insertion).